# In MicroStrategy Reporting Tool (MSTR), what is the difference between Numeric prompt, Big decimal prompt and Long prompt?

Tags: visualization, microstrategy

Numeric prompt is length 15 digits,
Big Decimal prompt is length 38 digits,
Long prompt is length 10 digits.

Why do we have long prompt with length just 10 when we have numeric prompt of length 15 digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Numeric prompt` and `Long prompt` have different data types.

|  | Name of prompt | Length | Datatype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Numeric | 15 | Integer or Decimal |
| 2. | Big Decimal | 38 | Integer or Decimal |
| 3. | Long | 10 | Integer |